# VMWare tools yum install: [Errno -1] Metadata file does not match checksum CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, yum, vmware-workstation

When trying to install vmware-tools via yum:

`yum install vmware-tools`

I get the following error:
`http://packages.vmware.com/packages/rhel7/x86_64/repodata/primary.xml.gz: [Errno -1] Metadata file does not match checksum`

I've already tried the following suggestions:

- yum clean all
- editing /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo and uncommenting the baseurl lines and commenting out the mirrorlist lines.

Without any success, is anyone experiencing the same issue?

This is a virtualised Centos 7 machine running in vmware workstation.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://www.vmware.com/uk/support/packages.html) link? It does not list CO7 - Also the yum repo is playing up anyway they are listing unpublished versions for CO6 when I last checked a day or two ago

Comment: I hadn't seen it, might explain why this is happening. It used to work though. But maybe they just dropped support on it. The workaround i've got in place now is installing VMWare tools through the VMWare Workstation. And skip the repo in `yum`.

Comment: I thought it used to work as well - so i'm glad i'm not going mad. I'll keep my eyes open anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the warning, you could disable the repository

(the name may vary; see `ls /etc/yum.repos.d`):

```
sudo yum-config-manager --disable vmware-tools
```

For Linux, install [open-vm-tools](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools) (after having `vmware-tool` removed):

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install open-vm-tools
```